# Why does `this` change when passing the function argument as string or reference?

Tags: javascript

Have a look at this:

```
var a = {
    b: function() {
      console.log(this); 
    }  
}

// Example 1
a.b(); // a

// Example 2    
eval('a.b()'); // a
    
// Example 3
setTimeout('a.b()', 100); // a

// Example 4
setTimeout(a.b, 100); // Window

// Example 5
var c = a.b;
c(); // Window
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7RG76/).

Assuming the *expected result* is what *I* expected...

#### Example 1

When calling `b()`, the property of an `Object`, `this` becomes the property's `Object`, here it's the parent `a`. It produces the expected result.

#### Example 2

`eval()` is meant to adopt its execution context of where it is called, in this case, `window`. It also produces the expected result.

#### Example 3

When passing a string to `setTimeout()`, I'd imagine it is ran through something very similar to `eval()`. It too produces the expected result.

#### Example 4

`this` becomes `Window` in this example. This is what I am interested in.

#### Example 5

Here the `this` becomes `Window`, because `c`'s parent object is `Window`.

1. When passing only a reference to a function (e.g. `a.b`), will its `this`  always be `Window` when called with `()`?
2. Is the only way to keep its `this` as `a` to pass it as a string to `setTimeout()` / `setInterval()`?

Comment: You might find this article useful: [Understanding Javascript 'this'](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)

Comment: Regarding your example 5: I would not say that it is `window` because it is `c`'s parent. It is `window` because there is no other context set. By default, the context is `window`. And regarding example 2: No, `eval` evaluates a string always in the global context. If `a` was not global, it would throw an error.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for your input. I'm a bit confused on `eval()` always executing in global context based on what I read. If it were true, wouldn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/mzwX4/) output `7` twice?

Comment: @alex: Oh sorry, I got confused myself. `setTimeout` and that stuff is evaluated in global scope.... sorry :-/

Comment: @Felix Way to confuse me :P BTW, do you have something to post as an answer?

Comment: @alex: Sorry ;) No, I don't know what I could add more...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When passing only a reference to a function (e.g. a.b), will its this always be Window when called with ()?

Yes

> Is the only way to keep its this as a to pass it as a string to setTimeout() / setInterval()?

No. Create a new function instead.

```
setTimeout(function() { a.b() }, 100);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer David. I can't believe an anonymous function didn't spring to mind.

Comment: but passing through a yet another function will be much slower if this is done lots of times, no?

Comment: @vsync — No. "Working" achieves the goal much faster than "Not working" (which takes infinite time). (And if you are adding an explicit delay, the time taken to create an invoke a function will be negligible in comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Developers are often confused about javascript's *this* keyword. The most important thing to remember is that it is provided by the call.

In the 4th example:

> ```
> // Example 4
> setTimeout(a.b, 100); // Window
> ```

the first argument is a reference to the function, so it's called without any "parent" object. Since the call doesn't provide an object, *this* is set to `window`.

Your comment on example 5:

> Here the this becomes Window, because
>   c's parent object is Window.

is not really incorrect. Because the function call doesn't provide an object to use as `this`, it is set to `window` (which is the default when no object is provided).

> Is the only way to keep its this as a
>   to pass it as a string to setTimeout()
>   / setInterval()?

No. Other than calling it as a property of an object, you can use `call` or `apply`:

```
var x = a.b;
x.call(a);
```