# Why does the context change in this JS snippet?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/raylu/C6Tkn/

```
function a() {
    document.write(this + '<br />');
}

a();
a.apply('hello');

var b = function() {
    a();
}
b.apply('hi');​
```

I would expect the last line to output 'hi', but instead it outputs window.

Comment: [MDN has a good page about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Whenever you call a function like `func();`, `this` will refer to the global object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does `this` change when passing the function argument as string or reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883619/why-does-this-change-when-passing-the-function-argument-as-string-or-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` is meant to be `window` in that context.

`b()`'s `this` is `'hi'`, but that isn't inherited/associated with any function calls in the body of the `b()` function. That is why `this` inside of `a()` when called via `b()` with the normal function invocation method (`()`) is `window`.